# How do I assign a command line argument to a Static variable in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am new to Rust. I am creating a Rust binary that takes a command line argument. I want to be able to use the command line argument string as a static constant string for the entirety of the application.

What is the right approach to doing that?

If I declare something static and I update it I am having to use `unsafe` everywhere I use it.

If I use `lazy_static` like below, I am not sure how to make the locally acquired &argv[1] accessible to a closure declared inside main

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref MYID: String = get_arg_value();
}

fn main() {

    let argsv: Vec<String> = std::env::args().collect();
    let get_arg_value = || -> String { argsv[1] }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the code inside the `lazy_static!`:

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref MID: String = {
        let argsv: Vec<_> = std::env::args().collect();
        argsv[1]
    };
}
```

But then you'll get an error "cannot move out of index". So clone the string (it's one-time initialization so perf doesn't matter):

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref MID: String = {
        let argsv: Vec<_> = std::env::args().collect();
        argsv[1].clone()
    };
}
```

Note that you don't really need the `Vec` - you can work with the iterator:

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref MID: String = std::env::args().nth(1).unwrap();
}
```

Also note that it's better to use [`once_cell`](https://lib.rs/crates/once_cell) as [it's going to be part of `std`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/lazy/).